# How to improve Electron error messages in terminal when using karma-electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, karma-runner

EDIT: I'm using [karma-electron](https://github.com/twolfson/karma-electron), maybe it is karma-electron creating traceless errors.

I see some errors in my terminal that seem to come from Electron through karma-electron, that are super difficult to work with. They look horrible:

```
Electron 2.0.17 (Node 8.9.3) ERROR
  {
    "message": "Uncaught TypeError: /Users/joepea/src/trusktr+infamous/src/html/behaviors/Behavior.js: Duplicate declaration \"whenDefined\"
(This is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error.)\nat /Users/joepea/src/trusktr+infamous/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/s
cope/index.js:343:7\n\nundefined",
    "str": "Uncaught TypeError: /Users/joepea/src/trusktr+infamous/src/html/behaviors/Behavior.js: Duplicate declaration \"whenDefined\" (Thi
s is an error on an internal node. Probably an internal error.)\nat /Users/joepea/src/trusktr+infamous/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope
/index.js:343:7\n\nundefined"
  }
```

Is that karma-electron output (I have a feeling it isn't Electron directly)?

How can I get better, formatted, clean stack traces in the output?

Comment: Can't you create a global error handler, and handle the error output from your end? Or is this part of a build process / test process?

Comment: Part of a test process, which I run as a `karma ...` command. The karma-electron plugin runs the tests in Electron.